# What could be causing this GFCI trip upon fan turn off?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a 2-pronged fan plugged into a GFCI in my basement. Twice now, as I was turning it off (out of maybe 30 times I have turned the fan off), the GFCI tripped.

Now, I understand that GFCIs trip when they detect a current imbalance, however, I'm at a loss to figure out what could have caused that current imbalance. Here are the relevant facts:

- The fan has a plastic case and buttons (except for the metal fan cage). I was not touching any metal part of the fan when turning it off.
- The fan sits on a wooden pallet and has rubber feet.
- The fan's cord is in good condition (it was running very close to some metal components, including the fan cage, but there are no cracks). In any case, why would a cord fault cause a GFCI trip only when the fan turns off?
- The GFCI is working properly (I have a drill press plugged into the same GFCI, no problems).

Where could the current imbalance be coming from?

As requested, pictures:
[image: of socket]
[image: of fan]

Comment: Is the drill-press (whatever that is?) unearthed too?

Comment: ARe you sure it's not a AFCI/GFCI Circuit Breaker. Those will break if there is a sufficient arc.

Comment: With the fan unplugged, check resistance at the plug between H -> Earth and N-> Earth.  Use your meter on MegOhms scale.

Comment: @Andyaka I guess the OP means the "test" button of the GFCI when he says "drill press".

Comment: A photo of your GFCI could be useful to diagnose the problem. Try to capture all the writings on its front panel cleanly. Photo(s) of the fan could be useful as well.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati I think he might mean one of [these](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1lIcmApBRVaBflnd-281h5GBqn71Z-QGR1iDke8pcOIOfxMMh) or [these](http://www.electricianmentor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/1.-main-WEN-8-inch-5-Speed-Drill-Press.png)

Comment: @Andyaka :-D That would be a good explanation for the leakage!

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Andyaka is correct: I meant a drill press with a 3-pronged, grounded plug very similar to the one he linked to.

Comment: @AlmostDone What exactly do you mean by "resistance between H->Earth"? You want me to ohm out the socket itself (with the circuit breaker off)?

Comment: By the way, is this behaviour repeatble? You could try at least a couple dozen times to switch the fan off and see if the GFCI trips with any regularity. Two events out of 30 is not very statistically significant. If it happens with some regularity, you might narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Andyaka Ouch! linguistic barrier in action here, I took it for a joke. Silly me! Rereading the phrase with the explanation of what "drill press" means clears it up! doh!

Comment: @LorenzoDonati It is NOT consistently reproducible, however, the only times I have tripped this GFCI are those two. So I think there is a linkage. (If you press a button and something happens which has never happened before, I would put the blame on something related to the button...)

Comment: @dpdt I think it is the drill press having an asymmetrical leakage to ground close to the trip limit. Along comes a surge or disturbance (that could **also** be as a result of the fan being activated) and the GFCI trips. You could (with utmost care and no children in the room) disconnect the drill-press earth lead and wire a sensitive ammeter between the disconnected earth wire and proper earth on the GFCI and take a measurement. EXTREME CARE NEEDED OF COURSE.

Comment: Well, if only those two times happened, it could be even something that you wasn't aware when it happened. For example, wet hands or ambient moisture together with poor insulation between the plastic buttons and the inner metal chassis. It's in the basement: if it is humid, some condensation inside the fan might explain the issue.

Comment: @dpdt, ohm out the plug on the cord attached to the fan.

Comment: @Andyaka I added photos. I also tried to reproduce the issue by turning the fan on and off ~10 times: no results. It is quite possible, though, that my problem has something to do with cumulative leakage currents from a bunch of sources: not only do I have the drill press (which was off) and the fan, but I also have an oscilloscope (3 prong), a DC power supply (3 prong), a soldering iron (3 prong), a 2-prong heat gun, a 2-prong fluorescent light, a cheap 2-prong wall-wart, and 2 power strips all plugged in.

Comment: Is there a chance your GFCI outlet also has ARC-Fault detection?

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions

There does not have to be any leakage to ground for a GFCI to trip.  There just has to be an unbalanced current detected.

A GFCI is like a balanced CM choke that reverse the polarity of one winding to use the differential current for activate a latching relay.

If the energy of the difference is enough to trip the breaker, it will.  But normally  the bandwidth of any transformer and CM chokes included cannot span much more than a few decades of frequency and the transient arc of a switched inductive load (fan) may span many more decades.  So I think the mathematical problem is how much energy is imbalanced in the windings over the whole bandwidth not just at the line frequency.  THe technical problem is the sensor is design for line frequency and the input here is an impulse.

The solution may be a 1 nF plastic cap ( rated for Vac) across the switch.  Then the problem may be during switch on.  So try an RC snubber across the switch resistor to limit the bandwidth to 1KHz for fBW~ 0.5 L/R or ~ 0.5 RC using 1nF.

To test for the problem , use the largest inductive load. ( transformer, solenoid, motor etc) THe probability to switch off during peak current is increased with the number of trials.  20 ought to be enough if marginal, 5 or less if significant. It must be stored energy not resistive.

Normally it is done by creating an inbalance of 100uA one line or the other of the GFCI CM Choke at line frequency which translates into 12mW * x ms? which will be less energy than the 1/2LI^2 of the inductive load being switched off. It will take much more energy to cause some of the spectrum to be imbalanced from mismatched windings as a function of geometry , stray capacitance and frequency.

Comment: Where else will the current imbalance come from? Kirchoff's Current Law states that current into hot prong = current out of neutral prong if there are no other current flow routes. Is the current being capacitively coupled to ground?

Comment: Its the flux that must be balanced not just the current  and my theory is that there enough imbalance on some kV switch impulse arc from switching LdI/dt at peak current that the balance is poor for some reason for this spectrum that does not show up at the fundamental due to CMRR vs f